# Converting cURL - from CLI to PHP

Tags: php, curl

Here is what I have to replicate:

```
curl --basic
     --user testuser:testuser
     --form xml=@newdoc.xml
     --form data1=@mynewfile.xml
     http://localhost:9263/repository/document
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9263/repository/document");
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array("xml"=>"@e:/path_to_file/old.xml","data1"=>"@e:/path_to_file/new.xml");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Discounting the fact that the API isn't returning an error, that the call to the API doesn't seem to be doing anything, is my CURL translation good? I'm just trying to remove things from the equation.

**Edit #1**: While sanitizing my post (and removing debug output), I had removed the $buffer = curl.exec($curl_handle) line...

**Edit #2**: Per Fanis' suggestion, I replaced the file calls

```
$old_xml_string = daisy_exec_query("http://localhost:9263/repository/document/8-Multimedia?branch=1&language=2");
//omited dom operations
$new_xml_string = $dom->saveXML();  
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9263/repository/document");
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array("xml"=>$old_xml_string,"data1"=>$new_xml_string);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: You're missing `curl_exec()` to actually perform the call. Other than that, the "@" operator from curl will not work like that in PHP's curl functions afaik, you'll need to get the file's contents into the variable as a string.

Comment: @Fanis during sanitizing, I had removed the exec call. I put it back into my example.

Comment: @Fanis post your suggestion (posting a string instead of a file) and I will accept it. I'm getting the same error I was getting using the CLI. Thus, it would be safe to say that it's now working as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help. The funny thing is that such a "bug" wouldn't even appear in any error logs, as there's no error. You'd only spot the missing HTTP call in your endpoint's access logs.

Comment: @Fanis that's what I meant, the API end of things wasn't showing any errors in it's log (but now does thanks to your fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting comment as answer as per TekiusFanatikus' suggestion)

The "@" operator from curl will not work like that in PHP's curl functions to include a file's contents. You'll need to get the file's contents into a variable as a string and pass that into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.